# PHP Update using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have my php file which contains my method to update the database. However, in Javascript how do I make it so every 5 seconds say it "visits" this page so it's contents gets updated.

Here is my update.php file:

```
<?php include('config.php') ?>

<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE paint SET paint_points='test'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Updated";
?>
```

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the terminology.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use AJAX.

Comment: use javascript setInterval and AJAX to send request to php for updating

Comment: Check for a javascript framework such as jQuery ($.ajax) there is all the code you need to do it.

Comment: Specially, you'll have a separate page that hosts the JavaScript call. You'll make an asynchronous call to update.php on a recursive loop. (or recursive promise/deferred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setInterval` function with an (a)jax request every 5 secs in javascript:

```
//syncronized jax:
function myjax() {
    var oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oXhr.open("POST", "yourphp.php", false);
    oXhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    oXhr.send(null);
}

//set an interval each 5 seconds to call your myjax method
setInterval(function() { myjax(); }, 5000);
```

In this example the request is synchronous but it could be asynchronous if you wished so.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest case is to reload the page with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setInterval(function() { location.reload(true); }, 5000);
</script>
```

You can get fancier if you use an ajax call to fetch the page.

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking to reload the entire page.

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee Maybe, however, it's not clear. One could wrap it into an iframe, if they don't feel comfortable with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
(function() {
    var updateAgain = arguments.callee;
    $.get('/url/to/script.php', function() {
        setTimeout(updateAgain, 5000);
    });
})();
```

The advantage of this over `setInterval` is that it won't start counting to five seconds until the request is finished; this is important if the request takes more than a second or two. It will also stop if a request fails (which may or may not be an advantage).